# Keypair-pubkey mismatch when partial signing - Python

Tags: python, web3.js

I am trying to create and partial sign a transaction for create an account, but I keep receiving a keypair mismatch error. My code looks like this:

```
from spl.token.instructions import create_associated_token_account
from solana.keypair import Keypair
from solana.publickey import PublicKey
from solana.transaction import Transaction

signer = Keypair()

create_transaction_instruction = create_associated_token_account(
    payer=PublicKey(mintFeePayer), owner=signer.public_key, mint=PublicKey(mintPublicKey)
)

transaction = Transaction()
transaction.add(
    create_transaction_instruction
)

transaction.sign_partial(signer)
```

I am using https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py which apparently is the most python unofficial library for this, I am open to use something else if it works.

And I always get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "kinetic_sdk/__main__.py", line 49, in <module>
    transaction.sign_partial(signer)
  File "/Users/alexramirez/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/kinetic-sdk--u4hmztD-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/solana/transaction.py", line 299, in sign_partial
    self._solders.partial_sign(underlying_signers, self._solders.message.recent_blockhash)
solders.SignerError: keypair-pubkey mismatch
make: *** [run_sdk] Error 1
```

Thanks.

Updated code just using `solders`:

```
from solders.message import Message
from solders.keypair import Keypair
from solders.instruction import Instruction, AccountMeta
from solders.hash import Hash
from solders.transaction import Transaction
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey

TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID = Pubkey.from_string('TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA')
ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID = Pubkey.from_string('ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL')
SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY = Pubkey.from_string('SysvarRent111111111111111111111111111111111')
ZERO_BYTES = bytes([0])
SYSTEM_PROGRAM_PROGRAM_ID = Pubkey.from_string('11111111111111111111111111111111')

owner = Keypair.from_base58_string('2an9mq3qY6e7PhGxHYRcw3JbpHLrBYgRzH5QBKgJZSxUUszYrgXQbRFZicuVWZLNiBzeUE3rgDma2EnYQKse8UpB')
fee_payer = Pubkey.from_string('MogXFseNqiFnRtk6wrDL9BDfKRZhjP5VBSiE1E35zeJ')

associated_token_address = Pubkey.from_string('3FuYhW79b3xbyixukA8pav6P9TgEwtCKPEhC1sULxBxG')

instruction = Instruction(
    ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    ZERO_BYTES,
    [
        AccountMeta(fee_payer, True, True),
        AccountMeta(associated_token_address, False, True),
        AccountMeta(owner.pubkey(), False, False),
        AccountMeta(SYSTEM_PROGRAM_PROGRAM_ID, False, False),
        AccountMeta(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, False, False),
        AccountMeta(SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY, False, False),
    ],
)

null_signer = NullSigner(owner.pubkey())

message = Message([instruction], owner.pubkey())
blockhash = Hash.default()  # replace with a real blockhash
transaction = Transaction([owner], message, blockhash)

print(transaction)
```

New Error:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'Transaction::sign failed with error NotEnoughSigners', /Users/runner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/solana-sdk-1.10.25/src/transaction/mod.rs:710:13
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "src/__main__.py", line 88, in <module>
    transaction = Transaction([owner], message, blockhash)
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: Transaction::sign failed with error NotEnoughSigners
make: *** [start] Error 1
```

Comment: have you tried making the payer and signer the same wallet? also, solana-py is one of if not the only library for interacting with Solana in python. tutorials and docs are lacking but its your best option.

Comment: Thanks @Pixeled Signing doesn't show any errors when using the same wallet, but In my case I am creating a new account (signer), so the payer should be a hot wallet with SOL, the signer which is a new account doesn't have any SOL on it to pay the fee, so the account it is not created. Do you have by any change an example for creating a new account? :)

Comment: I *think* the payer and the signer must be the same. here is a segment from the solana cookbook (https://solanacookbook.com/core-concepts/transactions.html#deep-dive). "All transactions require at least one writable account to sign the transaction. Once submitted, the writable signer account that is serialized first will be the fee payer. This account will pay for the cost of the transaction regardless of whether the transaction succeeds or fails. If the fee payer does not have a sufficient balance to pay the transaction fee, the transaction will be dropped."

Comment: Could you add the code used to send the transaction

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `solana-py` properly supports partial signing.  It only supports [`Keypair`](https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/master/src/solana/keypair.py), but lifts from the Rust SDK via [`solders`](https://pypi.org/project/solders).  The Rust SDK partial signing is implemented around a generic [`Signer` trait](https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/latest/solana_sdk/signer/trait.Signer.html#), one implementation of which is [`NullSigner`](https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/latest/solana_sdk/signer/null_signer/struct.NullSigner.html) (basically just a `Pubkey`) used as a place holder for absentee signers during partial signing.  You're getting that error because all signers are not specified in *some* form.  It may be easier to use `solders` directly as it [does provide](https://kevinheavey.github.io/solders/api_reference/null_signer.html) a `NullSigner` implementation.

Comment: Thank you @trent.sol, this is helpful. I was about to get to the conclusion that `solana-py` doesn't support partial signing. According to your suggestion of using `solders` do you mean that I should migrate my entire Transaction code from solana-py and reimplement it in solders or just the Instruction and the Signing part? I wonder if there is a sample code available.

Comment: sorry i don't know the internals of either of those modules sufficiently to say whether they're compatible or not.  from the docs, it looks like `solders` can do all the things on its own, though it's not pure python so installation may be complicated.

Comment: I started trying to implement it using solders, but yes, it is more difficult than I thought. I'll keep trying, but if there is a snippet to create an account instruction with solders, would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: again sorry, never used it, don't write much python.  i just browsed the docs/code of both modules and know how the core partial signing feature works since i co-wrote support for the rust SDK

Comment: I have updated my code and the question with solders, your hints have been helpful so far. Thanks.

Comment: While the logical constraints of Python-Rust communication mean that Solders can't have a function that takes a generic `Signer`, Solders does have a `partial_sign` method that accepts `Keypair`s, `Presigner`s or `NullSigner`s

Answer (score 0):

`solana-py` does support partial signing these days. You're just signing with the wrong keypair. The `payer` arg to `create_associated_token_account` needs to be the keypair that signs the tx, not the `owner`.

So you want something like:

```
from solana.keypair import Keypair
from solana.publickey import PublicKey
from solana.transaction import Transaction

signer = Keypair()

create_transaction_instruction = create_associated_token_account(
    payer=signer, owner=owner_pubkey, mint=PublicKey(mint_pubkey)
)

transaction = Transaction()
transaction.add(
    create_transaction_instruction
)

transaction.sign_partial(signer)
```

Comment: For reference, I wanted to reply here but there's limited space, so I posted a related comment here https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/issues/279#issuecomment-1254365872