# Transferring custom made solana tokens (not owned by me) from one wallet to another

Tags: solana-program, transactions, token, python, solana.py

So I am working on a script that transfers tokens (custom-made tokens not owned by me) from one wallet to another in python. How do I go about doing that?
(By tokens I mean, tokens like Dust, Luv, etc.)
And the info needed regarding the tokens, where do I get them from?

Answer (score 0):

I think a similar question to yours has been answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72665347/solana-transaction-using-python/73264835#73264835

please go through it and if you don't understand please reply

Comment: I tried that, but I got an error `solders.SignerError: keypair-pubkey mismatch`
How do I fix it? I got the secret key from my phantom wallet

Comment: This error is similar to this link [check it out](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1554/keypair-pubkey-mismatch-when-partial-signing-python)